# accessing the scratch org with access token obtain from devhub connected app?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I am developing automation script for our app and want to use connected app @DevHub to access my scratch org. Is it possible to do? I have tried but I am getting "“user hasn't approved this consumer” error when getting access token from devhub.

Comment: How are you getting access token? If you do create a default scratch org then its already authorized for you via CLI.

Comment: If I create connected app in my scratch org and run the automation script against that it works fine but what i want to do is get access token from DevHub and run the automation on scratch org. My automation is testing rest api written in Java

Answer (score 2):

Once you create Scratch orgs you can login into the Scratch org using one of the below methods headless

**JWT Server to Server oauth**

```
force:auth:jwt:grant
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_auth.htm

In this method, you will need to run below command with the private key of your connected app and also the consumer key of connected app

```
   $ sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -u me@acme.org -f <path to jwt key file> -i <OAuth client id> -r https://acme.my.salesforce.com
```

me@acme.org is the scratch org username if you log into the scratch org.

**SFDX URL Store**

```
force:auth:sfdxurl:store
```

This is documented here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_auth.htm

**NOTE:** Once you create a scratch org there is a `<username>.json` file created in `.sfdx` in your root folder. You can read the JSON and has an access token for the scratch org and also has the refresh token. You should use that to log in to the scratch org.

Comment: OK It does work on terminal using sfdx...grant but my automation script is not working. I just follow this in order for generating bearer token https://sfdcbeginner.com/how-to-use-oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow.html

Comment: follow the last sentences. Write a script to read the .json file for the scratch org username and that should have right access token to get into scratch org.

Comment: sorry for late response so I don't need to create connected app in the scratch org?

Comment: Yes you don’t need one!